# C++ sql errNo 1892470590

Tags: c++, mysql, exception

When I try to execute an SQL statement, I get an error that I couldn't find anywhere on the web...

[image]

```
string ifExist(string &query)
{
    Driver* theDriver;
    Connection* conn;
    Statement* theStatement;
    ResultSet* theResultSet;
    theDriver = get_driver_instance();
    conn = theDriver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "Password");
    theStatement = conn->createStatement();
    try
    {
        conn->setSchema("StudentManagementSystem");
        cout << query << endl;
        theResultSet = theStatement->executeQuery(query);
        return theResultSet->rowsCount() < 0 ? "true" : "false";

    } catch(sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        delete conn;
        std::cout <<"ERROR: "<< e.what() << endl;
        return "false";
    }
}    

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string tmp = "SELECT * FROM teacher";
    ifExist(tmp);
}
```

Headers:

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"


//Server files
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>

//Avoid redefinition of int8_t type
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define CPPCONN_DONT_TYPEDEF_MS_TYPES_TO_C99_TYPES 1

//mySql files
#include"mysql_connection.h"
#include<cppconn/driver.h>
#include<cppconn/exception.h>
#include<cppconn/statement.h>
#include<cppconn/resultset.h>
#include<cppconn/resultset_metadata.h>

//Input Output files
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace sql;
using namespace std;
```

Database: (the database is successfully created without errors)

```
        conn->setSchema("StudentManagementSystem");
        theStatement->executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE teacher(                              \
                                    teachID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,    \
                                    teachName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                     \
                                    teachSurname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                  \
                                    teachSubject VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,                  \
                                    teachPassword NVARCHAR(16) NOT NULL)"               );
```

When I debugged the `e.What()`, the error said:
+ e {sql_state="‹Æ_^]Â" errNo=1892470590 } sql::SQLException &

Does anyone know what errNo 1892470590 possibly can mean?

thank you for your time.

Comment: Never mind the errno ... is the descriptive error message not completely self-explanatory? You have rogue characters in your query. Probably an encoding problem.

Comment: I have not rogue characters in the query I sent to to executeQuery(). How do I counter these rogue characters in the executeQuery() statement?

Comment: How can I tell you that when I can't see them?

Comment: as you can see in the code above, "SELECT * FROM teacher" is sent to the query, however I am told that there is an error near uni code characters that doesn't exist in the query. What else would you like to see?